# Bubble chart - splunk

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, splunk

i am trying to create bubble chart in splunk with below code..

```
<dashboard>
    <label>Bubble Chart</label>
    <row>
        <panel>
            <chart>
                <searchString>index = _internal sourcetype=splunkd_access | stats count sum(bytes) as "Total Bytes" by  status, date_hour | table status date_hour count "Total Bytes"</searchString>
                <earliestTime>-7d</earliestTime>
                <latestTime>now</latestTime>
                <option name="charting.axisY.scale">log</option>
                <option name="charting.chart">bubble</option>
                <option name="charting.chart.bubbleMaximumSize">50</option>
                <option name="charting.chart.bubbleMinimumSize">10</option>
                <option name="charting.chart.bubbleSizeBy">area</option>
                <option name="charting.axisTitleY.text">Requests</option>
                <option name="charting.axisTitleX.text">Hour</option>
            </chart>
            <html>
                <p>Bubble Chart Options:</p>
                <code style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><![CDATA[<option name="charting.chart.bubbleMaximumSize">50</option>
 <option name="charting.chart.bubbleMinimumSize">10</option>
 <option name="charting.chart.bubbleSizeBy">area</option>]]></code>
            </html>
        </panel>
    </row>
</dashboard>
```

But as a result i am getting a Column chart but not a bubble chart.

it seems like i am doing something wrong, missing some package. what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your simplexml in my Splunk(6.3), the result is bubble chart.
So maybe your Splunk Version is too low?
[image]